# Failed to pass the id via a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables

I'm having this error when passing the variable ID for link_to. I'm not able to read the variable in the next page (blog_details.html.erb)

Error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in HomeController#blog_details

Couldn't find Post without an ID
```

My Home controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def blog
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def blog_details
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])   
  end

end
```

My link with variables:

```
<div class="post-title">                
  <h2 class="title">
    <%= link_to (post.titulo), :controller => 'home', 
          :action => 'blog_details', :post_id => post.id %>
  </h2>
</div>
```

Could someone help me with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like below:

```
def blog_details
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])   
end
```

or

```
<%= link_to (post.titulo), :controller => 'home', 
      :action => 'blog_details', :id => post.id %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are looking for `params[:id]` but passing in `:post_id`. So either look for `params[:post_id]`, or pass in `:id => post.id`

Answer (score 1):

You passed post_id instead of id :

This should work :

```
<div class="post-title">                
  <h2 class="title">
    <%= link_to (post.titulo), :controller => 'home', 
          :action => 'blog_details', :id => post.id %>
  </h2>
</div>
```

Consider using named routes or resources, so you can end with something like that :

`<%= link_to post.titulo, post %>`

Answer (score 0):

What is the path to home#blog_details?..with the path you can do something like:

```
<%= link_to (post.titulo),  blog_details_path(post) %>
```